# DNS not found from single Docker container running on Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment and application running the "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.2 running Docker" solution stack in a standard way. (I followed the AWS documentation.)

I have deployed a Dockerrun.aws.json file to it, and found that it has DNS issues.

To troubleshoot, I SSHed into the EC2 instance where it is running and found that on this instance an nslookup of any of the hostnames in question runs fine.

But, running the nslookup from within Docker such as with . . .

```
sudo run busybox nslookup www.google.com
```

. . . yields the result:

```
*** Can't find www.google.com: No answer
```

Adding the typical solutions such as passing the `--dns x.x.x.x` argument or `--network=host` arguments does not fix the issue. It still times out contacting DNS.

Any thoughts as to what the issue might be? Here is a Docker info:

```
$ sudo docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 30
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 29
 Images: 4
 Server Version: 19.03.6-ce
 Storage Driver: devicemapper
  Pool Name: docker-docker--pool
  Pool Blocksize: 524.3kB
  Base Device Size: 107.4GB
  Backing Filesystem: ext4
  Udev Sync Supported: true
  Data Space Used: 5.403GB
  Data Space Total: 12.72GB
  Data Space Available: 7.314GB
  Metadata Space Used: 3.965MB
  Metadata Space Total: 16.78MB
  Metadata Space Available: 12.81MB
  Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 1.271GB
  Deferred Removal Enabled: true
  Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
  Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
  Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-11-16)
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: ff48f57fc83a8c44cf4ad5d672424a98ba37ded6
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.14.181-108.257.amzn1.x86_64
 Operating System: Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 7.79GiB
 Name: 
 ID: 
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:

 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: the devicemapper storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.
```

Thank you

Comment: Just to update on this, the instance seems to be using cached DNS anyway that is working for what I need at the moment, so this is no longer a burning issue for me. It's still confusing why any nslookup in Docker fails though.